# Adding my remote public static IP to an Azure VNET so I can access a private VM inside the VNET

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-vm

I don't even know if this is possible. But I have a VM in azure running just private IP. I can access this VM from my azure web app when it is running in Azure.

But I need to develop against it and I am running VSCode etc locally and I'm able to access cosmodb and other azure services without issue. But I cannot access this VM as it is closed off publicly.

So I am wondering whether I can add my public static IP to the VNet that the service is running in. I cannot find anything via google about this so far but it seems like a common use case and maybe I am searching for the wrong thing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How can you add your public IP to a vnet?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add your IP to a Vnet, that's not something that Azure networking can achieve. To be able to access your VM from your home local machine you can look at a few options:

1. Add NSG rules to allow traffic from your IP to the specific ports on your VM, which port will depend on how you are doing your debugging and how you want to connect
2. Use Azure Bastion to then RDP/SSH to your VM from your machine
3. Create a VPN to connect your network to the Azure vNet, you can then access the machine as if it was on your network